# Generate array of resources in R.java at build time

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-resources, aapt

I have a library which uses about a thousand vector drawable files, each located in `res/drawable` under the name `ic_####.xml`. I am trying to replace my use of the `context.getResources().getIdentifier()` to get the drawables because it is stated in its documentation:

> Note: use of this function is discouraged. It is much more efficient
>   to retrieve resources by identifier than by name.

Plus, it kinds of pollute `R.java` file and using an array seems like a better solution. The problem is I have no idea how to generate this array at build time.

I thought maybe I could find a way to change how `R.java` is generated so that it contains an array of resource IDs for my drawables instead of individual keys, easily accessed with `R.icons[####]`, like this:

```
public static int[] icons = new int[]{0x7f090057, 0x7f090058, 0x7f090059, 0x7f09005a}
```

Is there any way to achieve this? Or a better solution?

Comment: Not sure it meets your specs but you can have an array of drawables as resource: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#TypedArray.

Comment: Yes I thought of it but there are still the individual drawables IDs in R.java and I still need to change the array everytime I had a new icon, but if it was a script at build time, it wouldn't be needed